# How to draw vertical spiral using TiKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw the following diagram :
[image]

I have tried to draw the diagram  using the following command :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dotted] (-4,-3) grid (4,7);
\draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 0.5cm);
    \draw[thick,->] (0,1) to [in=1, out=1](2,1.5)--(-2,2)--(2,2.5)--(-2,3)--(2,3.5)--(0,4);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields :
[image]
 But it does not give the actual diagram which I want. How can I draw the required diagram using TiKZ?

Comment: Search the site for spiral or coil

Answer (score 5):

Only new thing is the use of `bending` library to have bent arrow head.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dotted] (-4,-3) grid (4,7);
\draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 0.5cm);
    \draw[thick,decoration={aspect=0.31, segment length=7mm,
     amplitude=2cm,coil},decorate,arrows = {<[bend]-}] (0,4) --(0,1);
\node[draw,fill=white,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (0,1){};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to plot a spiral is to use parametric equations, i.e.,

```
t = [0..2*n*pi]
x = sin(t)
y = cos(t)
z = t
```

Very naively speaking, in this form, n indicated the number of spiral rounds and x,y coordinate is actually a circle. By providing some coefficient to the equation one can make conical spirals or generate clockwise/counter-clockwise spirals. I will leave the study of math to you. Here is a *basic* starting point that you can modify it meet your requirements.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
    view={0}{30},
    axis lines=none,
    ymin=-2,
    ymax=5,
    xmin=-2,
    xmax=2]

    \addplot3 [thick, ->, blue, domain=3:7*pi, samples = 100, samples y=0] ({sin(deg(-x))}, {cos(deg(-x))}, {x});
    \addplot3 [thick, red , domain=0:2*pi, samples = 100, samples y=0] ({sin(deg(x))}, {cos(deg(x))}, -3);
    \addplot3 [thick, only marks, blue, mark=o] ({sin(deg(-3))}, {cos(deg(-3)}, {3});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By playing around the gains, parameters and the axis view, you can generate what you want.