# Creating a Pyramid with equilateral triangular base

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I would like to create a pyramid with an equilateral triangular base such as shown on the right here:

[image]

I haven't been able to find any guidance on such a figure. I would I create such a figure in Latex (Tikz)?

Comment: What you try so far? Your question as it is, is to broad and will be probably closed.

Comment: by the way this kind of pyramid is called a tetrahedron.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430690/121799) are some options.

Comment: @jtsbattle At right picture, is `d_{DA} = d_{DC}= d`?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your right picture correctly, then `DA = DC = AB = BC = CA = d`, so `H` lies on the perpendicular bisector of the segment `AC` in the plane `(ABC)`. This code satisfies all your conditions.

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm,tikz]{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
 \begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{70}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={d=6;}]
     \path (0,0,0)       coordinate (A) 
         (d/2,d/2,0)     coordinate (H) 
          (d,0,0)        coordinate (C) 
            (d/2,{d*sqrt(3)/2},0)    coordinate (B) 
          (d/2,d/2,{d/sqrt(2)}) coordinate (D) 
          ($ (A)!0.5!(C) $) coordinate (M);
 \foreach \p in {A,B,C,H,D,M}
 \draw[fill=black] (\p) circle (1.5pt);
 \foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,B/-90,C/-90,D/90,H/-70,M/-135}
 \path (\p)+(\g:3mm) node{$\p$};
 \draw (D) -- (A) (D) -- (B) (D) -- (C) (A) -- (C) -- (B);
 \draw [dashed] (A) -- (B) (D) -- (H) (B) -- (M);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

I check by *Maple*
[image]