# Tangent, Normal and Binormal Vectors

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, asymptote, drawing

I want to draw a schematic figure which illustrates the coordinate system relationship between the Cartesian coordinate system and the helix natural coordinate system. Which tools (eg. tikz-3dplot,  asymptote) are more suitable for drawing this?

[image: Coordinate system transformation]

Comment: a better title: "TANGENT, NORMAL AND BINORMAL VECTORS"

Comment: I recommend using Asymptote, and have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620306/140722 and some formulas https://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/~plaval/math2203/TNB.pdf

Answer (score 9):

I use some maths formulae are in [here](https://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/%7Eplaval/math2203/TNB.pdf) and [the Frenet–Serret frame (or TNB frame)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas).

[image]

With avaiable formulae, Asymptote code is plain and simple. Hidden lines can be dashed, but I don't like that, because `(T,N,B)` also are dashed then ^^

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
import graph3;
currentprojection=orthographic(3,2,1.5,center=true,zoom=.9);
real a=2;
real h=8;
draw(scale(a,a,h)*unitcylinder,yellow+opacity(.3));
draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint,black),O--4X,gray,Arrow3());
draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint,black),O--4Y,gray,Arrow3());
draw(Label("$z$",EndPoint,black),O--10Z,gray,Arrow3());

triple r(real t){return (a*cos(t),a*sin(t),h*t/(2*pi));}
real tmin=0,tmax=2pi;
path3 g=graph(r,tmin,tmax,operator..);
draw(g,red+.6pt);

triple T(real t){return (-a*sin(t),a*cos(t),h/(2*pi));}
triple N(real t){return (-a*cos(t),-a*sin(t),0);}

pen pentan=purple;
pen pennor=red;
pen penbin=darkgreen;


real t=1;
triple P=r(t);
triple Pt=unit(T(t));         // the tangent vector at P
triple Pn=unit(N(t));         // the normal vector at P
triple Pb=cross(Pt,Pn);       // the binormal vector at P
draw(Label("$T$",EndPoint,pentan),P--P+Pt,pentan,Arrow3);
draw(Label("$N$",EndPoint,pennor),P--P+Pn,pennor,Arrow3);
draw(Label("$B$",EndPoint,penbin),P--P+Pb,penbin,Arrow3);

real s=3;
triple Q=r(s);
triple Qt=unit(T(s));         // the tangent vector at Q
triple Qn=unit(N(s));         // the normal vector at Q
triple Qb=cross(Qt,Qn);       // the binormal vector at Q
draw(Q--Q+Qt,pentan,Arrow3);
draw(Q--Q+Qn,pennor,Arrow3);
draw(Q--Q+Qb,penbin,Arrow3);

real c=4.3;
triple R=r(c);
triple Rt=unit(T(c));         // the tangent vector at R
triple Rn=unit(N(c));         // the normal vector at R
triple Rb=cross(Qt,Qn);       // the binormal vector at R
draw(R--R+Rt,pentan,Arrow3);
draw(R--R+Rn,pennor,Arrow3);
draw(R--R+Rb,penbin,Arrow3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would like to know how to use Tikz package to draw "TANGENT, NORMAL AND BINORMAL VECTORS" of a 3D parametric curve.

Comment: If you want to draw with TikZ or some TikZ-based packages, like `pgfplots` or `3dtools`, you can define `cross` product, or manually calculate it

Answer (score 2):

A Ti*k*Z solution. It uses `3d` and `perspective` libraries to avoid some trigonometric calculations.

I'm also creating two `\pic`s one for the helix and another one for the three vectors. This way we can draw either of them writing only the involved angles.

**The code:**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\tikzset
{
  surface/.style={draw=cyan,left color=cyan,fill opacity=0.5},
  top/.style={draw=cyan,fill=cyan!30,fill opacity=0.5,canvas is xy plane at z=4},
  pics/helix/.style 2 args={code=% #1 = initial angle, #2 = final angle
    {\draw[pic actions] plot[domain=#1:#2,samples=0.5*#2-0.5*#1+1] ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},\x/180);}},
  pics/vectors/.style={code=% #1 = angle
    {\draw[green!50!black,-latex,opacity=0.3] ({cos(#1)},{sin(#1)},#1/180) -- ({0.4*cos(#1)},{0.4*sin(#1)},#1/180) node[pos=1.5] {$\vec N$};
     \begin{scope}[shift={({cos(#1)},{sin(#1)},#1/180)},rotate around z=90+#1,canvas is xz plane at y=0]
       \draw[blue!50!black,-latex]    (0,0) --++ ({atan(1/pi)}:0.75) node[pos=1.4] {$\vec T$};
       \draw[magenta!50!black,-latex] (0,0) --++ ({90+atan(1/pi)}:1) node[pos=1.3] {$\vec B$};
     \end{scope}}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view,rotate around z=180,font=\small,
                    line cap=round,line join=round]
% axes
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[left]  {\strut$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[right] {\strut$y$};
% helix,   background
\pic[red] {helix={135}{315}};
\pic[red] {helix={495}{675}};
% z-axis,  background
\draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4);
% vectors, background
\foreach\i in {270,550}
  \pic {vectors=\i};
% cylinder
\draw[surface] (-45:1) arc (-45:135:1) --++ (0,0,4) arc (135:-45:1) -- cycle;
\draw[top] (0,0) circle (1);
% z-axis,  foreground
\draw[-latex] (0,0,4) -- (0,0,5.5) node[above] {$z$};
% helix,   foreground
\pic[red] {helix=  {0}{135}};
\pic[red] {helix={315}{495}};
\pic[red] {helix={675}{720}};
% vectors, foreground
\foreach\i in {30,110}
  \pic {vectors=\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**The output:**

[image]