# Strands wrapping cylinders

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing, braids

I want to draw the following figure on TikZ. But I don't know how to draw wrapping strands.
I already have a code for the cylinders as:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno,english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%cylinder
\draw [thick](-1.5,-2) -- (-1.5,2);
\draw [thick](+1.5,-2) -- (+1.5,2);
\draw [thick](-1.5,-2) arc (180:360:1.5 and 0.5);         
\draw[thick,dashed] (1.5,-2) arc (-2:180:1.5 and 0.5);  
\draw [thick](-1.5,+2) arc (180:360:1.5 and 0.5);         
\draw [thick](+1.5,+2) arc (-1.5:180:1.5 and 0.5);         
%hollow
\draw [thick](-1,-2) -- (-1,2);
\draw [thick](+1,-2) -- (+1,2);
\draw [thick](-1,-2) arc (180:360:1 and 0.25);
\draw[thick,dashed] (1,-2) arc (-1.65:180:1 and 0.25);
\draw [thick](-1,2) arc (180:360:1 and 0.25);
\draw [thick](+1,2) arc (-1:180:1 and 0.25);
\node[left,scale=0.7] at (-1,2) {$T_0$};
\node[right,scale=0.7] at (1.5,2) {$T_1$};
\fill[fill=blue] (1.5,2) circle (1.5pt);
\fill[fill=red] (-1,2) circle (1.5pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204211/47927 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/620283/47927 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of `\foreach` loops and with the help of Ti*k*Z `perspective` library for the isometric (or another) view.

You need to have in mind the order for the 'layers' too. First draw the background and then the foreground.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view]
% background
\foreach[count=\ii]\i in {blue,red} \foreach[count=\jj]\j in {dashed,solid}
{
   % radius
   \pgfmathsetmacro\r{3-\ii}
   % cylinder surface
   \fill[left color=white,right color=\i,fill opacity=0.1] (135:\r) arc (135:-45:\r) --++ (0,0,6) arc (-45:135:\r) -- cycle; 
   % ellipses
   \draw[\i,\j] (135:\r) + (0,0,6*\jj-6) arc (135:-45:\r); 
   % helices
   \foreach\z in {0,3}
     \draw[dashed,\i] plot[domain=180:360,samples=145] ({\r*cos(\x+45)},{-\r*sin(\x+45)},\z+\x/120);
}
% foreground
\foreach[count=\ii]\i in {red,blue}
{
   % cylinder surface
   \draw[\i,left color=\i,fill opacity=0.4] (135:\ii) arc (135:315:\ii) --++ (0,0,6) arc (315:135:\ii) -- cycle;
   % helices
   \foreach\z in {0,3}
     \draw[\i] plot[domain=0:180,samples=145] ({\ii*cos(\x+45)},{-\ii*sin(\x+45)},\z+\x/120);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I will study your solution.

Comment: I have a problem with your answer. I cannot separately change the red and blue strands. In my picture, the red strand starts let's say at the point (-1,0) on the inner circle(yours starts at (1,0)) and it makes 3 turns. How do I do this according to your code?

Comment: If the strands are different you probably need to draw them separately. So remove the `\foreach ... {blue,red}` loops and draw each one with its own specifications

Comment: I removed the loops but all I get is 'No PDF' error. I am not very good at TikZ,. Can you give me an example?